# Phoenix assets taking incredibly long time to compile when using Elm

Tags: compilation, phoenix-framework, elm, brunch

My asset compilation in Phoenix is taking around 20 to 60 seconds each time, and it seems to be related to adding Elm to the project. What would cause this to happen?

Comment: I totally share your desire to improve up compile times, but *20 to 60 seconds* is *incredibly long time* these days? Seriously? I must be living in the future without knowing it ;-)
+1 for the answer though. Thanks to you I got our compile times 60x faster with one line in `.bablerc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out this was happening because I wasn't telling brunch not to use the ES6 compiler on Elm code. It was compiling Elm code to a 10,000+ line javascript file and *then* trying to compile that through Babel. This is fixable by either putting the Elm code in the `vendor` folder (which is ignored by Babel by the default Brunch settings) or telling Babel specifically to ignore the (in my case) `main.js` file that is the output of the Elm code compilation.

Comment: Webpack Config should have `module.noParse: /\.elm$/,`.
https://www.elm-tutorial.org/en/04-starting/03-webpack-1.html#webpack-config